# EXCEL VBA access data on a closed file

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

In excel (let's say workbook1.xlsm) following formula fills in a value from a another file:
='G:\networkdrive\temp[info.xlsx]sheet1'!$B$1

This file can be closed or even offline (network drive not available)
I assume that this sheet is stored within workbook1.xlsm
The file appears as a link: **Data->edit link**
This works fine.

Question 1: **where are these data stored?** in an object within the file? cached?

What I want to achieve is to do a search on a closed file that is on a drive that is not available (traveling) but it's data is available through "data->link", this  with VBA in a local stored file.

Question 2: **is it possible to access data using vba on a linked file?** If yes how?
Thank you

Comment: The current value is stored as a property of the cell. You cannot access values that are not stored as the result of formulas.

Comment: what a pitty, anyway, thank you for the answer